# How to copy text to clipboard in Vaadin without addon

Tags: javascript, copy, vaadin, clipboard

I have spent long, too long, trying to make all of the directory components work. They took something that could have been super simple and made it complex and difficult.

I finally buckled and tried to copy a javascript function into my project and it worked with a simple method. The method, like all others need to be initiated by some other component. But do that in any way you want it.

All I'll leave here is the code. And the hope that somebody else will find this and use less time than I did.

```
void copyText(String text){
    Page page = UI.getCurrent().getPage();
    page.executeJavaScript(
                    "var el = document.createElement('textarea');" +
                    "el.value = $0;" +
                    "el.setAttribute('readonly', '');" +
                    "el.style = {" +
                    "   position: 'absolute'," +
                    "   left: '-9999px'" +
                    "};" +
                    "document.body.appendChild(el);" +
                    "el.select();" +
                    "document.execCommand('copy');" +
                    "document.body.removeChild(el);",
            text);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested if this works in Safari?

Comment: I have not. I read that the javascript code should work on anything above IE8. I'll test it tomorrow and get back to it. According to this, https://josephkhan.me/javascript-copy-clipboard-safari/, it should work as the logic with his code and the above is the same.

Comment: You made one of the addons in the directory, right? Is there any "best practice" for copy-to-clipboard that I am unaware of? I only made this thread in hope that it would help and not misguide others (if anyone). If you have something to share, please do.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there were some browser-specific differences earlier, but I haven't looked at it in a while. I just remember that it's not trivial to get it working right on all platforms. That's the reason I asked about Safari; I don't have a Mac so I can't test it myself. It might be a good idea to test with different mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void copyText(String text){
    Page page = UI.getCurrent().getPage();
    page.executeJavaScript(
                "var el = document.createElement('textarea');" +
                "el.value = $0;" +
                "el.setAttribute('readonly', '');" +
                "el.style = {" +
                "   position: 'absolute'," +
                "   left: '-9999px'" +
                "};" +
                "document.body.appendChild(el);" +
                "el.select();" +
                "document.execCommand('copy');" +
                "document.body.removeChild(el);",
        text);
}
```

Just to further explain the code. We need to initialize the page and then execute plain javascript-code. In this code, I pass the String text as a parameter and the utilize it in the code as "$0".

The code creates a textarea, which most of the addons in the directory also does. It then sets the text-string, it hide it from the ui with some styling. Then the textarea gets added to our file, because you are only allowed to copy a value that is visible. Then the text is selected, copied, and lastly the textarea is removed. Fast and clean.

You can also add the following line:

```
el.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
```

Add it after the el.select(); line. According to W3, it should work better on phones with this line, but I have not tested it.